# Looking for AWS CLI command to include Public IP, Private IP, VPC, Instance state, name & type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I need to extract details from AWS in two parts:

Query 1. Command to extract containing Instance name, Public IP, running state, VPC's (with their associated tags ie Production) & instance type

Query 2. Command to extract ALL IP's that belong to a any VPC with a tag of 'scheduling', the instance name, type and if they're in a 'running' state.

For the 1st if these queries I guess I could build on a command I was very kindly given by an AWS guru:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,VpcId,PublicIpAddress,State.Name,Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value]" --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running
```

the trick comes in adding further options successfully and getting it to work!

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Oh yeah -- and if I could output it to a csv file that'd be an absolute bonus!

Comment: If it is trick to do it with CLI, do it with Python.